# Create 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create 2 arrays in JS from an input value. The first should contain all my inputs values and the second one should contain all my inputs values but for the last one.
I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<body>
<input type="text"></input>
<button>click</button>
<script>
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click" , clickHandler , false);

var valori = [];
var comp = [];

function clickHandler()
{

n = input.value;
    for (var i =0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    valori.push(parseInt(n));           
    comp = valori.pop();
    console.log(valori);            
    console.log(comp);          
    break;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

The ideea is that I want to check if an input value has been entered before. I thought of doing that by creating 2 arrays like I mentioned before and then compare "n" to the "comp" array

Comment: What does `lasp one` mean?

Comment: `pop` removes an element from the array. Are you sure you want to be removing values from your array?

Comment: sorry to say but still its not clear what exactly u want.. why u used the for loop as u are break the loop. and u will get the value in **comp** array but not in **valori** as first u inserted the value in **valori** then u pop the element into **comp** which mean u moved the value in COMP and remove it from **valori** so you will not get any value in **valori**

Comment: I will suggest you to give a proper question title please, not like this one.. and have posted my answer no need to create two array and for loop u can try with **indexOf(n)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are just to check element exist or not.. why dont u why `indexOf(n)`??

no need to create two array and for loop etc etc.. just indexOf will work for you..

check the below code..

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text"></input>
<button>click</button>
<script>
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click" , clickHandler , false);

var valori = [];
function clickHandler()
{
    if(isNaN(input.value))
    {
        alert('value is not a Number');
    }
    else
    {
        var nbr = parseInt(input.value);
        if(valori.indexOf(nbr) < 0)
        {
            valori.push(nbr);
            input.value="";
        }
        else
        {
            alert('element already exists.');
        }   
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

U are setting value on comp which is array u need to set value at index .

```
 function clickHandler()
 {
    var is  = true;
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("inp").value);

    if(!isNaN(n))
   {
      for (var i =0; i < valori.length; i++)
       {
        if(n === valori[i])
        {
            console.log("duplicate");
            is  = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(is)
        valori.push(n); 
  }
   console.log(valori);   
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w4buQ/3/)

Comment: what is the use of for loop and the variable u create the javascript referring the button and input?? no.. right?? and did u read the question what exactly he want to do?

Comment: @DeepakSharma donot be aggressive .. I was just pointing out mistake .. and i updated the ans,, and i am not calming to have best solution either so don't be hyper...